# PHP and SQL: using login session variable not updating the database correctly

Tags: php, sql, validation, session

I am creating a page where a user can calculate their BMI and then save this to their profile. First I validate the BMI. However, when I perform this calculation now, it is inserting '0.99' into the database instead of the correct BMI value. I have been debugging and think it has something to do with the connection to the database (have tried moving this around to other areas of the script but it isn't making a difference).

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css" />
<body>
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL &~ E_NOTICE);

    // Start the session
    session_start();


    // Make sure the browser is transmitting in UTF-8
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

        // Clear the error message
    $error_msg = "";

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
        echo $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'help_me_be_healthy') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8");


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $bmi=0;
        $kg=$_POST['kg'];
        $mt=$_POST['mt'];

        if(empty($kg) || empty($mt))
        {
            echo "<label class='err'><center>All fields are required</center></label>";
            include("index.php");
        }

        else if(!is_numeric($kg) && !is_numeric($mt) )
        {
            echo "<label class='err'>Please enter valid data.</label>";
            include("index.php");
        }
        else
        {
            $bmi = $kg/($mt*$mt);
            $bmi=round($bmi,2);
            if ( $bmi <= 18.5 ) 
            {
                echo "Your BMI is " .$bmi."  which means you are underweight";

            }

            else if ( $bmi>18.5 && $bmi <= 24.9) {
                echo  "Your BMI is ".$bmi." which means you are normal";
            }

            else if ( $bmi>29.9 && $bmi> 24.9 ) {
                echo "Your BMI is ".$bmi." which means you are overweight";
            }

            else if ( $bmi >29.9 && $bmi<=39.9 ) {
                echo "Your BMI is ".$bmi." which means you are obese";

            }
            else
            {
                echo "You are morbidly obese.";

            } 
            include("index.php");

            //$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_bmi`= '$bmi' 
            //WHERE `user_id` = ($_SESSION = ['user_id'])";

            //echo $_SESSION['user_id'];



            //if (!isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
            //$query = "SELECT * FROM 'users'";
            $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_bmi`= '$bmi' WHERE `user_id` = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
            //}
            //else {
            //  $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_bmi`= '$bmi' WHERE `user_id` = '" . $_GET['user_id'] . "'";
            //}

            $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
            print "\n----\nLookup:\n";
            print "Num rows: " . mysqli_num_rows($data);
            print "\n";
            print_r($row);
            print '</pre>';
            return;

        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated:)

Sarah

Comment: have you echoed the bmi before updating it?
what is the columntype of user_bmi?

Comment: This isn't causing your error but I suspect where you've got `$bmi>29.9 && $bmi> 24.9` you probably mean `$bmi<29.9 && $bmi> 24.9`

Comment: @demonking the BMI value being calculated is displayed correctly. BMI type is set to float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming BMI is being calculated correctly/displayed, and the `user_bmi` column is a float/double/numeric/decimal, the `UPDATE` doesn't need quotes around the value so the SQL should be:

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_bmi`=$bmi WHERE `user_id`=".
    $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

(`user_id` my also not need to be escaped, depending if it's a number or a string)

Also, you cannot get a query result (fetch_assoc) from an UPDATE SQL command... if you'd like to know the number of effected rows use [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php):

```
print "Num rows: ".mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
```

What makes you think the BMI is going in incorrectly, are you sure the `user_id` is correct, how are you looking into the database to determine what's stored?

*Updated Code Printout code:*

```
if (!mysqli_query($dbc,$query)) {
   echo "Failed to store";
}
echo "<pre>\n----\nLookup:\nQuery:$query\n".
  "Num rows:".mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)."\n</pre>\n";
```

Comment: Hi,I am echoing the user_id and it is returning the correct value. I know that the value is being updated because if I create a new user and then calculate the BMI '0.99' is added to the database for that user.

Comment: removing the quotes around the sql statement results in nothing being returned (a blank page).

Comment: currently i am getting this on the site: 36Your BMI is 36.09 which means you are obese36.09 ---- Lookup: Num rows:

Comment: lookup and num rows are for debugging purposes only: these are empty which is what makes me think this is something to do with the connection to the database

Comment: hi @rudu i have added 'echo $bmi' after the sql query and the correct value is returned

Comment: thanks @Rudu this is what i am getting now: 36Your BMI is 22.68 which means you are normal22.68
----
Lookup:
Query:UPDATE `users` SET `user_bmi`= '22.68' WHERE `user_id` = '36'
Num rows:0

Comment: removed the quotes; num rows still equals to 0. updated query: $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_bmi`= $bmi WHERE `user_id` = " . $_SESSION['user_id'];

Comment: And in the SQL table `users` there's a row with user_id=36?  If you copy/paste the SQL you're getting from the query line (lookup output above) into an SQL editor and run it on the database... what happens?

Comment: interesting..still displaying 0.99 (changed it to 0 then updated again, value changed to 0.99)

Comment: that's it! had to change float from (2,2) to (4,2)